# Auto download when jquery countdown gets zero

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to automatically download the file when the countdown gets zero in jquery/PHP.

Comment: What countdown? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes, but you need to give more detail how your counter HTML looks now, so someone can give you example. 
Rough suggestion is to use on change event on counter value, or initiate a loop where you will monitor counter changes, and when counter have 0 value initiate download simulating click on link using trigger().

Edit - You can extend your counter code as given below.

```
interval = setInterval(function() {
        countdownElement.firstChild.data = 'You can start your download in ' + (seconds - second) + ' seconds';
        if (second >= seconds) {
            downloadButton.style.display = 'block';
            $('#download > a').trigger('click');
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        second++;
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: In your counter control script after line downloadButton.style.display = 'block'; ... add: $('#download > a').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code assuming you use plain javascript:

```
var link = document.getElementById('download').firstChild;    

interval = setInterval(function() {
    countdownElement.firstChild.data = 'You can start your download in ' + (seconds - second) + ' seconds';
    if (second >= seconds) {
        downloadButton.style.display = 'block';
        clearInterval(interval);
        link.click();
        //OR
        link.onclick();
    }
    second++;
}, 1000);
```

A jQuery Version (because you tagged your question with jQuery):

```
var link = $('#download').find('a').first();    

interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#countdown').html('You can start your download in ' + (seconds - second) + ' seconds');
    if (second >= seconds) {
        downloadButton.show();
        clearInterval(interval);
        link.click();
        //OR
        link.trigger('click');
    }
    second++;
}, 1000);
```

Please add some code next time and don't only post a link to a website in the comments